# How can I get rid of this account-bound item?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do with a second Staff of Herding plan?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/74259/what-can-i-do-with-a-second-staff-of-herding-plan)

I have the Staff of Herding recipe in my inventory. I have already taught this recipe to my Blacksmith (this is my second copy).

- I can't teach it to the Blacksmith again.
- I can't drop it on the ground, since it is account bound.
- I can't sell it to a vendor, since it can't be sold.
- I can't sell it on the auction house, since it is account bound.

How do I get rid of this thing?

Comment: It was made unremovable from your inventory as a hotfix to reduce the support load from people complaining about dropping it, accidentally selling it, etc. As @OrigamiRobot answered, it will be properly patched in 1.0.7.

Answer (score 5):

In [patch 1.0.7](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/8414570/Public_Test_Realm_--_Patch_107_Notes-1_15_2013), you will be able to sell it to a vendor for 0 gold or drop it on the ground.

Comment: So for now, I'm stuck with it?

Comment: @StrixVaria for now try giving it to a newly created character and delete him